# Checking for an internet connection on mobile devices in C++Builder XE8

Tags: android, c++builder, c++builder-xe8

I found Delphi code on this article:

[Checking for an internet connection on mobile devices with Delphi XE5](http://delphi.radsoft.com.au/2013/11/checking-for-an-internet-connection-on-mobile-devices-with-delphi-xe5/)

I need something similar for C++Builder, not Delphi.

Comment: So you are looking for a translation service? You can just use the pascal code as is. Put it in a .pas file and add that file to your project.

Comment: But i´m using the c++ builder, can i call the .pas file without problem?

Comment: Yes i know that you use C++Builder as i can read. Well try it out. Not THE pas file. What do you mean? Put relevant code in a .pas file and add to project. And ask on Embarcadero forum. Ask Remy Lebeau.

Comment: @VictorZepeda: yes, you can use Delphi code in a C++Builder project.  The majority of the RTL/VCL/FMX library code is written in Delphi, so C++Builder includes a Delphi compiler. Like greenapps said, put the Delphi code in a `.pas` source file (the demo already includes several `.pas` files, just wrap the checking code in a function within a new `.pas` file as needed), add it to your C++ project, and compile it.  A C++ `.hpp` file will be generated that you can then `#include` in your C++ code where needed.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers!!! Yeah, i´ve seen that FMX is written in Delphi!!